# How to generate the AST of a Coq source code?

Tags: ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree, coq

I'm trying to write a Coq source code formatter, and I want the AST for a Coq source code.

Firstly I tried to generate ASTs from [the official Coq library](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/api/index.html) but gave it up because I couldn't know how.

After googling for a while, I found that [coq-lsp](https://github.com/ejgallego/coq-lsp/) seemed to [have the ability to generate parsing-level ASTs](https://coq.discourse.group/t/is-there-a-way-to-extract-asts-from-the-coq-compiler/1950). Given that, I wrote the following code.

```ml
let opts =
  {
    Coq.Init.load_module = (fun _ -> ());
    Coq.Init.load_plugin = (fun _ -> ());
    Coq.Init.fb_handler = (fun _ -> ());
    Coq.Init.debug = false;
  }

let code =
  {|Inductive day : Type :=
  | monday
  | tuesday
  | wednesday
  | thursday
  | friday
  | saturday
  | sunday.
|}

let code_stream = Gramlib.Stream.of_string code
let init_state = Coq.Init.coq_init opts
let parser = Coq.Parsing.Parsable.make code_stream
let result = Coq.Parsing.parse ~st:init_state parser
let (Coq.Protect.R.Completed (Stdlib.Ok (Some ast))) = result.r
```

```
(executable
 (public_name foo)
 (name main)
 (libraries foo coq-lsp.coq coq-core.gramlib)
 (flags
  (:standard -rectypes)))
```

The above code compiles, and I can get the AST.

```
utop # #rectypes;;
utop # #use "bin/main.ml";;
val opts : Coq.Init.coq_opts =
  {Coq.Init.fb_handler = <fun>; load_module = <fun>; 
   load_plugin = <fun>; debug = false}
val code : string =
  "Inductive day : Type :=\n     | monday\n     | tuesday\n     | wednesday\n     | thursday\n     | friday\n     | saturday\n     | sunday.\n   "
val code_stream : char Gramlib.Stream.t = <abstr>
val init_state : Coq.State.t = <abstr>
val parser : Coq.Parsing.Parsable.t = <abstr>
val result : (Coq.Ast.t option, Loc.t) Coq.Protect.E.t =
  {Coq.Protect.E.r = Coq.Protect.R.Completed (Stdlib.Ok (Some <abstr>));
   feedback = []}
File "bin/main.ml", line 28, characters 4-52:
28 | let (Coq.Protect.R.Completed (Stdlib.Ok (Some ast))) = result.r
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Warning 8 [partial-match]: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
Completed (Ok None)
val ast : Coq.Ast.t = <abstr>
```

However, it doesn't always generates ASTs for valid Coq codes.

If I replace the `code` with this:

```ml
let code = {|Example foo: 1 = 1.
Proof.
Abort.|}
```

The `result` contains an error.

```
val result : (Coq.Ast.t option, Loc.t) Coq.Protect.E.t =
  {Coq.Protect.E.r =
    Coq.Protect.R.Completed
     (Stdlib.Error
       (Coq.Protect.Error.User
         (Some
           {Loc.fname = Loc.ToplevelInput; line_nb = 1; 
            bol_pos = 0; line_nb_last = 1; bol_pos_last = 0; 
            bp = 15; ep = 16},
          <abstr>)));
```

Certainly, both Coq codes in the `code` are valid. Setting `Coq.Init.debug = true` didn't give any information.

Why does `Coq.Parsing.parse` reject the latter code, or even how can I get ASTs of any valid Coq code? I don't stick to using `coq-lsp`, but I'd like to generate them from raw codes (i.e., contents in `.v` files) if possible.

#### Versions

Ocaml: 4.14.1

coq-lsp: 0.1.6.1+8.17

coq-core: 8.17.1

utop: 2.13.0

Comment: You should start by printing the error message. It is why it is there)

Comment: Is this project publicly hosted anywhere? I would love to follow the development or even contribute as I have wanted a real Coq formatter for a while and have even considered writing one myself.

Comment: @Bridge Yes: https://github.com/toku-sa-n/coqfmt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I could get the AST using the official Coq library.

```ml
(* This function follows the instructions written in
   https://coq.github.io/doc/master/api/coq-core/Coqinit/index.html. *)
let init_coq () =
  let args, () =
    Coqinit.parse_arguments
      ~parse_extra:(fun _ -> ((), []))
      ~usage:
        Boot.Usage.
          { executable_name = "coqfmt"; extra_args = ""; extra_options = "" }
      ()
  in
  let cmds = Coqinit.init_runtime args in
  Coqinit.start_library ~top:Names.DirPath.initial cmds

let generate_ast code =
  let mode = Ltac_plugin.G_ltac.classic_proof_mode in
  let entry = Pvernac.main_entry (Some mode) in
  let code_stream = Gramlib.Stream.of_string code in
  let init_parser = Pcoq.Parsable.make code_stream in
  let rec f parser =
    match Pcoq.Entry.parse entry parser with
    | None -> []
    | Some ast -> ast :: f parser
  in
  f init_parser
;;

init_coq ()

let code = "Example foo:1=1. Proof. reflexivity. Qed.";;

generate_ast code
|> List.map (fun x ->
       Ppvernac.pr_vernac x |> Pp.string_of_ppcmds |> print_endline)
```

```
(executable
 (public_name fooo)
 (name main)
 (libraries coq-core.plugins.ltac))
```

```
%dune exec ./bin/main.exe
Example foo : 1 = 1.               
Proof.
reflexivity.
Qed.
```

`init_coq` is necessary. The program can compile without it but will generate an error below.

```
Fatal error: exception Gramlib.Stream.Error("'.' expected after [gallina] (in [vernac_aux])")
```

Note that the above code cannot be run on the Ocaml toplevel.

```
utop # #use "bin/main.ml";;
val init_coq : unit -> unit = <fun>
val generate_ast : string -> Vernacexpr.vernac_control list = <fun>
Exception:
Invalid_argument
 "The dynlink.cma library cannot be used inside the OCaml top-level".
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first code was not working because you didn't load the prelude and ltac plugin properly, the error would have done that.

You may have better luck using the new `fcc` compiler in `coq-lsp` 0.1.7.

You can easily write a plugin to print the Ast of a document.